# Iterating search query through KnockoutJS Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, sorting, knockout.js

**How do I live-update-sort a KO `observableArray()` and perform one function on each object that gets sorted and another function on an object that remains?**

So I've got an `observableArray()` of Google Maps Markers. 100+, so I'm trying to work out a sorting system that shows or hides the marker depending on if it matches a particular filter. I've used knockoutJS for the vast majority of the data bits in the app, so I'm trying to figure out how to best implement this. I can step through the array and get the titles via `gMarkers()[i].title`, but I'm not sure how to filter these items per another `observable()`.

I've created `userQuery()` to accept an input, so I can use that to sort. I assume this has to be done via a `ko.computed()`, but I'm not sure how to best update this as it's going to be something changing on the fly as people type (changing `userQuery()`).

Is there a lightweight way to iterate through the array and perform a function on each result dependent on the sort, or should I be approaching this from a different way?

Comment: hi again :) could you show the code? it would be a lot easier to understand

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dy70fe16/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use a (pure)Computed:

```
/// .... in your viewmodel ....
this.filteredData = ko.pureComputed(function() {
     // query all observables the outcome depends on
     var query = self.userQuery();
     var ...   = ... 

     var fData = []; 
     // iterate over your dataset or use ko.utils.map / ko.utils.filter
     for (...) { 
         fData.push(...); 
     }
     return fData;
});
```

The computed will recalculate whenever any observable you depend on changes. Be careful to not introduce cycles in your dependencies.